# StreamReader fails on Spanish Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I use the code below to import a CSV file, was using the VB reader but had the same problem.  Basically on my system and others I have tested it works but on Windows 8 ESP (Spanish) it fails.  I was able to work around the problem by opening the imported file in Visual Studio and saving it with encoding (US-ASCII - Codepage 20127) and Line endings CR/LF.  My guess is it is the CR/LF setting but am not sure.  I don't have Spanish Windows to test on so kind of awkward to determine the exact solution.  I can't keep manually changing the input file.

Edit:  I do know in the Spanish row.length always returns <= 5 so no data is imported.  I don't know if it is reading the whole file as one line (CR not work) or it is not splitting the lines ";" not working.

Any idea why Spanish Windows is not reading the file correctly and or how to work around it?

```
var frm = new OpenFileDialog();
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
var styles = System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None;
var delimiters = new char[] { ';' };
var trims = new char[] { '"' };
if (frm.ShowDialog() ?? false)
{
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(frm.FileName))
{
    string input;
    while((input = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var rows = input.Split(delimiters);
        for(int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
        {
            rows[i] = rows[i].TrimStart(trims).TrimEnd(trims);
        }
        DateTime expiration;
        if (rows.Length > 5 && DateTime.TryParse(rows[4], culture, styles, out expiration))
        {
            new Pin()
                {
                    ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    PinCode = rows[0],
                    Name = rows[1],
                    Area = rows[5],
                    DeviceId = "",
                    Expiration = expiration,
                    IsSold = false
                });
        }
    }
}
}
```

sample data:

```
"Code";"Profile name";"Profile type";"Duration";"Expiration date";"WiFi Area";
"99999";"10 peso 1 hour";"One-Time";"60  Mins";"2015-06-19 23:59:59";"company"
```

Comment: Without sample data it is not possible to answer. Note that using "utf8 with BOM" (.Net default for StreamReader/Writer) to save files makes guessing encoding thing of the past.

Comment: If you don't know the text file encoding, and you won't know in a far-flung place where people with your first name are called Juan, then always gamble on Encoding.Default.  You need a config setting of course.

Comment: Do you have a spec for your CSV file, including character set encoding?

Comment: Added sample data.  Note csv file is downloaded from website so I don't have specs or control of it.  My system just imports it.

Comment: Where are you running it from? Might be a spanish letter not avaliable in english although I have my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

This sticks out like a eye sore:

```
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

Why do you do this? Why not get the CultureInfo of the current system the code is running on?

Comment: Date format in Spanish usually is DD/MM/YYYY, so yes, maybe that would be adding some noise

Comment: I only use the culture for date parsing, it does not affect the rest of the code. Code never gets to the date parsing part, will add edit to original.